# Who would normally accuse political opponents of being foreign agents?

Tags: ukrainian-language, andriy-lyubka, carbide

When facing criticism of the Fountain project (which was actually cover for the smuggling tunnel), the mayor of Vedmediv accused the critics of being foreign agents:

> Much to Zola Burton's credit, he didn't let any of those slanderous remarks get to him. **As per usual**, he called all of his opponents "bought-and-paid-for foreign agents."

Who was this "usual" for? Is that usual for the mayor in particular, or was this common behavior for politicians in general?

Comment: Either could work.